# MVC DropDown List with Code First Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a couple of basic models, one for Products and one for Categories.
How can I relate the two in the model, so that when adding a new product, I can select the category the product belongs to, from a DropDownList?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 - With Tools Update and Razor syntax with HTML 5 markup.

I've been trying to get this working with no luck, can someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working...Just watched the Mix 11 Keynote with Scott Hansselmen.

The working code...

```
 public class Product
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
 }

 public class Category
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
 }
```

Now when creating the Controllers, MVC will generate a dropdownlist for the catetgories on the Products create page. Thus allowing you to select the category a product belongs too.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two tables like this (and their related classes):

**Product**

- ProductID
- CategoryID
- ProductName
- ....

**Category**

- CategoryID
- Category Name
- ...

Create a new class for a Helper, then add a method of type IEnumerable< SelectListItem > to return a list of Categories in the format of (value, text):

```
public class ListHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategoryList()
        {
            using (SiteDataContext db = new SiteDataContext())
            {
                var list = from l in db.Categories()
                           orderby l.CategoryName
                           select new SelectListItem { Value = l.CategoryID.ToString(), Text = l.CategoryName };

                return list.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

In your view, add a combobox to use this method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Category</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Select a category:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryID, Helpers.ListHelper.GetCategoryList())
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Product Name:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>

        ...

    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

Then in your post Action just get the Product object and save it to database:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                productService.InsertProduct(product);
                productService.Save();
                ...
            }
            else
            {
                return View(product);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Product entity needs to have a property of Category, you can then create a dropdown with all the categories and make it select the Category for the chosen Product.

I know there are examples of this here on the site but you can just as easy find an example with the help of google.